# Laravel 4.1 eager relationship "with" ignoring constraint clause

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

```
// class User
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'user_roles', 'uid', 'rid');
}

// class Role
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'user_roles', 'rid', 'uid');
}

// sql
-- user
id | name | other fields

-- user_role
id | name

-- user_roles, uid fk to user and rid fk to user_role
uid | rid
```

I am trying to load users with a certain role, i.e. load all editors, with the following code:

```
<?php
$roleName = 'editors';
return \User::with(array('roles' => function($query) use($roleName) {
    $query->where('name', '=', $roleName);
}))->get();
```

The above code returns every user, ignoring the $query->where. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs for [with](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) and [whereHas](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) . The latter is what you want here:

```
return \User::whereHas('roles', function($query) use($roleName) {
    $query->where('name', '=', $roleName);
})->get();
```

Comment: I was missing the difference between with and whereHas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

another option that you can also try:

```
$role = new Role::find($role_id);
return $role->users->all();
```

This will return all users

or if you have some wheres:

```
$role = new Role::find($role_id);
return $role->users()->where('name','like','%foo%')->get();
```

this will return all users with like name of foo